# Disable an asp:RequiredFieldValidator if a checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have 2 textboxes with required field validators, a button and a checkbox.  When the check box is checked I want to disable the required field validator on the second textbox and allow the button to be clicked when the first textbox is completed.

This is generally what my aspx page looks like, although this is just a made up example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" ControlToValidate="Name" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Name Required" runat="server" />
Name: <asp:Textbox ID="Name" runat="server"/>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvID" ControlToValidate="Name" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="ID Required" runat="server" />
ID: <asp:Textbox ID="ID" runat="server"/>

<asp:Button ID="btn" Text="Query" runat="server"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chxNoID" Text="I don't have an ID yet" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use javascript. Get the checkbox change event & put the code below in function

```
var ctrl1 = document.getElementById('<%=rfvID.ClientID%>');
                    ValidatorEnable(ctrl1, false);
```

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh Sorry but i don't refer this link . I had given answer from my implemented code before.Thanks for the link still

Comment: That okay. I just want to make sure that users get some more details