# js/asp enabling requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a checkbox and 2 required field validators attached to drop downs. If checkbox is checked then disable validators, if uncheck then validate. I'm able to disable 1 of them using the below I found here: [Disable an asp:RequiredFieldValidator if a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155608/disable-an-asprequiredfieldvalidator-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)

How can I use the below for both validators and then re-enable the validators once it is unchecked? (can be jquery)

```
function GrowthValidation() {
    var ctrl1 = document.getElementById('<%= Valid_MDCGrowth1.ClientID%>'); 
    ValidatorEnable(ctrl1, false);

    var ctrl2 = document.getElementById('<%= Valid_MDCGrowth2.ClientID%>'); 
    ValidatorEnable(ctrl2, false);
}
```

Comment: You need to first attach a change event to your checkbox. In the event, verify if checked use ValidatorEnable(ctrl1, false); if not than ValidatorEnable(ctrl1, true); for both validators.

Comment: Yes, my function already fires each time its checked/unchecked and understand that's what I need but how do I write that out?

Answer (score 0):

An example (not asp.net) just for you see the picture:Assuming you can use Jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#chkvalidate').change(function(){

    //If checked then disable both validators
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        var ctrl1 = document.getElementById('<%=rfvID.ClientID%>');
        ValidatorEnable(ctrl1, false);

        var ctrl2 = document.getElementById('<%= Valid_MDCGrowth2.ClientID%>'); 
        ValidatorEnable(ctrl2, false);
    }     
    //if not, enable
    else{
        var ctrl1 = document.getElementById('<%=rfvID.ClientID%>');
        ValidatorEnable(ctrl1, true);

        var ctrl2 = document.getElementById('<%= Valid_MDCGrowth2.ClientID%>'); 
        ValidatorEnable(ctrl2, true);
    }             
});
});
```

You can also refer to this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1175267.aspx

Comment: It disables both but does not show that it re-enables them.

Comment: You are saying that This disable them, but does not enable again?

Comment: Correct. Atleast it is not showing "*Required" after my button click once "re-enabled"

Comment: Did you check the link I provide? There is a comment that sugests this instead:

var validator = $get('<%=validator.ClientID %>');

validator.enable = true;
ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validator);